# Rectangle selection on canvas inside React component on MouseMove event

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to be able to make rectangle selections inside a canvas element.
Here's a small codepen that shows an approximate functionality I'm trying to implement: http://codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/pen/EZyBjm

I've googled around and found several examples, but they mostly didn't use `canvas` element, but a `div` instead. I tried to integrate this "`div` approach" into my React component, but it didn't work.

I have a controlled React component called `CanvasVideo` that controlls the `canvas` element, here's a part of it:

```
export default class CanvasVideo extends Component {
    // ............... more stuff above ...........
    getCanvas() {
        return this.refs.canvas;
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="canvas-video">
                <canvas
                    height={this.props.height}
                    ref="canvas"
                    width={this.props.width}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I use this component inside another component called `VideoContainer`:

```
class VideoContainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { video } = this.refs;

        // this is how I can access the actual canvas DOM element.
        const canvas = video.getCanvas();
    }
    render() {
        const videoSrc = {
            src: 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4',
            type: 'video/mp4'
        };

        return (
            <div className="canvas-video">
                <CanvasVideo
                    autoPlay={true}
                    height={480}
                    width={640}
                    loop={true}
                    muted={true}
                    ref='video'
                    src={videoSrc}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Inside my `VideoContainer` I need to be able to make rectangle selections, similar to those in [codepen above](http://codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/pen/EZyBjm), get the coordinates of that rectangle relative to the canvas size and on the `mouseup` event assign these coordinates into the state of `VideoContainer` component.

I've tried to integrate [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/d9BPz/546/) into my component, but the selections didn't work and moreover, it is in itself a bit buggy.

---

Could you please help me to implement this functionality correctly?

Comment: Sorry it was not clear to me what is your problem? The problem is not actually  anything react related but the canvas selection? The second example can draw over a canvas and the implementation of that?

Comment: @FabioCosta Well, the second example actually cannot draw over a canvas (if you change the div element there into a canvas element, the example will break). My problem is about integrating the functionality from the first example into my react component. And the thing is, the first example doesn't work with canvas either, only divs. That's why I've posted the question here, on SO. I think the question is still React-related because it's about using refs correctly, setting the right event listeners on components, and, altogether, it's about implementing the functionality I need "the React way".

Comment: Some stuff on React are not so well defined. If you need to do crazy stuff with the dom the react way would be using what you are already using of Refs and so on. The more React way IMO would be to pass something like a <Selection> component and redraw but if I understood correctly redrawn is not desired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [demo implementation](http://codepen.io/giladaya/pen/QdGLmZ) of a React component for rectangular selection using canvas.

This is the heart of the logic:

```
  onMouseDown = (e) => {
    this.isDrag = true
    this.curX = this.startX = e.offsetX
    this.curY = this.startY = e.offsetY
    requestAnimationFrame(this.updateCanvas)
  };

  onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (! this.isDrag) return
    this.curX = e.offsetX
    this.curY = e.offsetY
  };

  onMouseUp = (e) => {
    this.isDrag = false

    const rect = {
      x: Math.min(this.startX, this.curX),
      y: Math.min(this.startY, this.curY),
      w: Math.abs(e.offsetX - this.startX),
      h: Math.abs(e.offsetY - this.startY),
    }
    this.props.onSelected(rect)
  };
```

Note that this component uses requestAnimationFrame to schedule the canvas drawing for better performance.

If I understand correctly, you need to draw more things on the canvas. If so, you can either use the component as an overlay on top of another canvas component, or modify it to draw the other things you need.

Comment: "you can either use the component as an overlay on top of another canvas component" --> how do I do an overlay?